# How to round QWidget corners

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside

[image]

I wonder if there is there a way to round Qt widget corners?

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class Custom(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.setWindowOpacity(0.9)
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.Popup|QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setWindowTitle('Custom')
        self.resize(440,220)
        self.move(QtGui.QCursor.pos())

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        event.accept()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.close() 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Custom()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use `QWidget.setMask(self, QRegion)` for it.

An example in C++:

```
QWidget *widget = new QWidget;
widget->resize(300, 200);

const int radius = 10;

QPainterPath path;
path.addRoundedRect(widget->rect(), radius, radius);
QRegion mask = QRegion(path.toFillPolygon().toPolygon());
widget->setMask(mask);

widget->show();
```

Answer (score 5):

## SOLUTION:

[image]

Here is working Python solution  outlined by [hank](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1465625/hank) using C++:

```
import sys
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

class Custom(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.setWindowOpacity(0.9)
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.Popup|QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setWindowTitle('Custom')

        radius = 40.0
        path = QtGui.QPainterPath()
        self.resize(440,220)
        path.addRoundedRect(QtCore.QRectF(self.rect()), radius, radius)
        mask = QtGui.QRegion(path.toFillPolygon().toPolygon())
        self.setMask(mask)
        self.move(QtGui.QCursor.pos())

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        event.accept()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.close() 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Custom()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

It works if your widget is static, but if you want to resize it and still have rounded corners, there is the `paintEvent` method you need to override. It should look like this:

```cpp
void Widget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    const int radius = 7;

    QPainterPath path;
    path.addRoundedRect(rect(), radius, radius);
    QRegion mask = QRegion(path.toFillPolygon().toPolygon());
    setMask(mask);

    QWidget::paintEvent(event);
}
```